# vidyo.io: Moving and resizing a video using VidyoConnector API

Tags: video-conferencing

I downloaded the latest iOS package from vidyo.io and have successfully built my application integrated with the Vidyo libraries and using the VidyoConnector API.

When my app first comes up, I was very happy to see that a preview video appears on the screen just where I’d expect it to be! However, when moving the view to a different location, the video did not render quite how I intended.

The video did move to the x/y position on screen that I’d hoped but the size did not adjust to my new view dimensions. Then I found the **VidyoConnectorShowViewAt** API call and that did indeed resize my view but the positioning of the video then was off.

Is this the correct call to make when moving and resizing a view? Does anybody have any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow! Could you please add empty lines to your question (by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40165449/edit)) so that it is a bit more structured?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are pretty close. If you are just moving your view to different coordinates without resizing, then no API call is necessary. But if also resizing, then indeed use VidyoConnectorShowViewAt. My hunch is that your coordinates that you are passing are off, as x and y should be relative to the view itself and not to the main view. So try passing 0 and 0 as x and y and see if that helps.